# Rails console is not accepting my environment change

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to run `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate` on my development environment but after running the following I get an error:

```
$ rails about
audited 11 packages in 0.474s
found 0 vulnerabilities

About your application's environment
Rails version             5.2.3
Ruby version              2.5.5-p157 (x86_64-darwin18)
RubyGems version          2.7.6.2
Rack version              2.0.7
JavaScript Runtime        Node.js (V8)
Middleware                Rack::Cors, Rack::Sendfile, ActionDispatch::Static, ActionDispatch::Executor, ActiveSupport::Cache::Strategy::LocalCache::Middleware, Rack::Runtime, Rack::MethodOverride, ActionDispatch::RequestId, ActionDispatch::RemoteIp, Rails::Rack::Logger, ActionDispatch::ShowExceptions, WebConsole::Middleware, ActionDispatch::DebugExceptions, ActionDispatch::Reloader, ActionDispatch::Callbacks, ActiveRecord::Migration::CheckPending, ActionDispatch::Cookies, ActionDispatch::Session::ActiveRecordStore, ActionDispatch::Flash, ActionDispatch::ContentSecurityPolicy::Middleware, Rack::Head, Rack::ConditionalGet, Rack::ETag, Rack::TempfileReaper, Warden::Manager, Mailjet::Rack::Endpoint, ScoutApm::Middleware, ScoutApm::Instant::Middleware, Bullet::Rack
Application root          ROOT
Environment               development
Database adapter          postgresql
Database schema version   20190910214159

$ RAILS_ENV=development rake db:drop db:create db:migrate
audited 11 packages in 0.495s
found 0 vulnerabilities

rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::ProtectedEnvironmentError: You are attempting to run a destructive action against your 'production' database.
If you are sure you want to continue, run the same command with the environment variable:
DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1

Tasks: TOP => db:drop => db:check_protected_environments
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea why it's trying to run the command on my production database?

Here's my database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: development-database
  url: postgres:///development-database
  pool: 5
  username: name
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: production-database
  user: name
```

Comment: Can you post your `database.yml` file?

Comment: what happens if you do `rake db:drop RAILS_ENV=development`?

Comment: Why i see a lot of different issues from `Rails5.2.X`, am i missing smth from that version ?

Comment: I've added the `database.yml`

Comment: try running `rails db:environment:set RAILS_ENV=development`, it might be that your `ar_internal_metadata` table has that value set to prod. It might be possible that you migrated data from prod to your env database ?, not sure, but try that and see if it works.

Comment: You are totally right.  I literally just did that

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
rails DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 db:drop db:create db:migrate
```

it would work for you.

Comment: I'm worried to do that as I do not want to impact my production DB

Comment: Then I would suggest to backup your db as export and run:

```rails DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1 RAILS_ENV=development db:drop db:create db:migrate
```